# Internal documents .tex in overleaf

Tags: overleaf

i have a little question:

> Is there any way to use a .tex document inside another in Overleaf? As a linked object.

What i mean is: I want to link some documents (Gráficos 1, 2 and 3) in the main document, like that:

[image]

I need to do this because the graphics are timing out and i don't like to include figures in .png or .jpg.

Comment: Do you mean you want to integrate the results (meaning the PDF) of your other projects into your new project, or do you want to reuse the same source? The latter is easily possible using `\input` or `\include` (search for the difference), but doesn't give you any speed advantage. The former could be done by compiling your other files as the main file and uploading the resulting PDF to your new project.

Comment: oh, i thought it would give me an advantage when compiling... btw, thanks :)

Comment: Well, including the resulting PDFs would be much faster, if that's an option.

Comment: It could be a huge advantage compiling the previews, if you comment every `\input` or `\include` except for the subdocument where you are actually working, or using `\includeonly`. On the other hand, if the problem are only the images... Are you aware of the `draft` option?